# Uploading files from multiple directories to an SFTP site using Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, sftp

I'm trying to upload items from multiple folder locations locally to an SFTP site. I'm using an existing shell script that I know works for uploads from a single local location, but I can't figure out how to make it work for uploads from multiple local locations.

I'm fairly new to coding and have only basic experience with batch scripting and some minor editing of existing shell scripts, so I would appreciate any help that can be given.

Here's the sample of my existing single local location upload script

```
open sftp://(userid):(password)@(sftp site) -hostkey="(hostkey)"

pwd
ls
lcd "(local directory)"
lls
cd (remote directory)
ls
put * -filemask=|*/ ./
exit
```

This has worked well for us previously, but I'm trying to clean up some of our existing scripts by combining them into one process that runs as an automated task, but I can't figure out how to chain multiple tasks like this together.

Comment: What SFTP client are you using? You say "shell script", but the code you posted looks like [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the upload code for each location:

```
cd /remote/directory

lcd /local/directory1
put * -filemask=|*/ ./

lcd /local/directory2
put * -filemask=|*/ ./
```

---

Though if it's really a WinSCP script, you can use just one command like:

```
put -filemask=|*/ /local/directory1/* /local/directory2/* /remote/directory/
```

See the documentation for the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

> `put <file> [ [ <file2> ... ] <directory>/[ <newname> ] ]`
>
> ...
>
> If more parameters are specified, all except the last one specify set of files to upload. Filename can be replaced with Windows wildcard to select multiple files. To upload all files in a directory, use mask `*`.
>
> The last parameter specifies target remote directory and optionally [operation mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/operation_mask) to store file(s) under different name. Target directory must end with slash. ...